# Can I declare a character encoding when using XStreamingElement to write a large XML file?

Tags: .net, xml

I'm using XDocument and XElement objects to write a large XML file (currently 8MB). I'd like to switch to XStreamingElement so that I can write the file without having all the data in memory at once. Unfortunately, I need to include an encoding declaration. Can I do that without using an XDocument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use XmlWriterSettings to specify the encoding when you create the XmlWriter. It generates the declaration automatically.

```
var doc =
    new XStreamingElement("openerp",
        LoadReferenceData(),
        LoadAccounts(),
        LoadPartners(),
        LoadComponents());
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
settings.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("latin1");
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(
    outputFilename.Text,
    settings))
{
    doc.WriteTo(writer);
}
```

Each of the Load methods returns IEnumerable and uses `yield return` to generate XML as it loops through a database query result.